# ImportError: cannot import name libsvm

Tags: python

```
……

……/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/**__init__**.py in <module>()  
     40   
     41 # expose sub packages as directories  
---> 42 from . import converters  
     43 from . import proto  
     44 from . import models  


……/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/**__init__**.py in <module>()  
      5   
      6 # expose directories as imports  
----> 7 from . import libsvm  
      8 from . import sklearn  
      9 from . import xgboost
```

**ImportError: cannot import name libsvm**

This is the error in Jupyter Notebook. But I find there are the files include libsvm in that path. And the version of the file libsvm is the newest.
Who know the cause of this error? And how to solve it?

Comment: Please include output of `pip freeze`.